# react js which col number value with function call. Failed prop type: invalid prop 'md' of type function supplied to Col, expected number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react js component which has Col element as defined

```
<Col md= {3}>

</Col>
```

When I used a number like 3 or 2, it works fine.

I added a function to check for an incoming props bool value and switch between 3 and 2 like the following

```
<Col md={ this.getColVal}>
</Col>

getColVal = () => {
  return (this.props.IsValue === true) ?  3 : 2;
}
```

Also tried in the constructor

```
const colVal = (this.props.IsValue === true) ?  3 : 2;
```

I am getting this error

Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'md' of type 'function' supplied to 'Col', expected number

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply use `<Col md={ (this.props.IsValue === true) ?  3 : 2 }></Col>`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the getColVal method as below:

```
<Col md={ this.getColVal()}>
</Col>
```

by using above approach you will get the integer return value.

Comment: He was getting a function, not undefined, otherwise, you're right.

Comment: awesome. Thanks.